# Is this fruit naturally shaped like a woman?

Tags: fruit

There were some news reports in July 2016 about a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m6-d0QFylvM) of a tree in Thailand that produced fruit in the shape of a naked woman.

- [Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3671387/Tree-bears-fruit-shape-women-discovered-Thailand.html)
- [Drama Fever](https://www.dramafever.com/news/video-mysterious-tree-in-thailand-grows-fruit-shaped-like-women/)

This is apparently consistent with [Nariphon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nariphon) from Buddhist mythology.

[image: Still from YouTube video]

Is this a hoax?

Comment: I don't see any way of verifying that claim. Neither article mention specifics such as where the tree is or a name of someone making the claim. Given the lack of details, I would think it's a fake but there is nothing but weakish visual evidence to go on.

Comment: Creating strange shaped fruits by allowing the fruit to grow in a mould is fairly common, I expect that that's what this is (unless it's completely fake)

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This looks like a pretty well executed hoax (assuming it is one) and there seems to be no clear method to determine their authenticity. [Human shaped roots](http://www.hardingsginsengfarm.com/rootglry.htm) already exist, and there doesn't seem to be an *a priori* reason why human shaped fruits can't exist.

Comment: Correct. The one in snopes simply presume it's hoax because it's well, too beautiful to be real. Botanists do not know that because it's a miracle tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been pretty well debunked by [Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/narilatha-flower/).

> If such a flower or fruit actually exists outside of folklore, it's unknown to botanists. We haven't found reference to such a plant in any handbooks or textbooks of botany. That having been said, neither are there obvious signs that the images and video have been tampered with, which leaves only one logical explanation for the existence of the one-of-a-kind photographic "evidence" above: namely, that the "narilatha flowers" shown were carefully constructed physical props designed to fool us, entertain us, or both.

Comment: I wouldn't describe it as "pretty well debunked". Snopes simply asserts that it is unknown to botanists, without giving references.

Comment: And I wouldn't ask it here if it's pretty well debunked. Actually I should.